# Struggling configuring LightDM

Tags: lightdm, customization

I've been trying to customize my lock screen for a while now but I'm running some issues now. I' running Ubuntu 21.10. I installed LightDm with "sudo apt install lightdm" but everytime I install LightDm, it never creates the lightdm.conf file in ¨/etc/lightdm/¨ neither lightdm-gtk-greeter that cames by default as I've seen from some tutorials. Inside ¨/etc/lightdm¨ there's only 2 files: an empty dir named: lightdm.conf.d and users.conf that have this inside:

```
#User accounts configuration

 #NOTE: If you have AccountsService installed on your system, then LightDM will
 #use this instead and these settings will be ignored

 #minimum-uid = Minimum UID required to be shown in greeter
 #hidden-users = Users that are not shown to the user
 #hidden-shells = Shells that indicate a user cannot login

[UserList]
#minimum-uid=500
#hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess
#hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin /sbin/nologin
```

---

Inside ¨/usr/share/lightdm¨ there are 2 dir: guest-session & lightdm.conf.d
Now, Inside that lightdm.conf.d there are some files:

[image: files inside lightdm.conf.d]

I removed lightdm using: sudo apt rm lightdm, sudo purge lightdm, I used sudo apt-get autoremove after everything, I also deleted manually lightdm files from etc and usr, installed lightdm again and same issue.

One time lightdm.conf was created after installation but it was empty.

I know is a large text, I apologize for that but I'm new using Linux and I'm loving it so far, but I still want to customize everything I can and also learn.

Comment: There is no `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`; I see only a `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` file in that directory (https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/amd64/lightdm/filelist).  You haven't said what desktop you're using, but have you tried `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings`  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings)

Comment: Using gnome 40. It seems that what I get when intallng lightdm is unity-greeter (found some files in /etc. When I open users.conf, what is inside is this:
file:///home/h0tcheetos/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202021-11-01%2003-06-35.png

Comment: you are not expecting  that we can see files/image in your $HOME :D when I read the ubuntu wiki right you can create /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf  by your own. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM